# fade in / out banner

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to create a fade in / out banner on my website.
I have an array of id's. I want to loop through the array thus showing first after a time limit and hiding then going to the second array to repeat the same proceedure.

my code....

```
$(Document).ready(function () {
var images = new Array();
images[0] = "#bannerImageOne";
images[1] = "#bannerImageTwo";
$('#homeCarousel img').hide();

for (var i in images) {
    setTimeout(fadeInOut(i, images), 5000);
    //alert(i);
}
});


function fadeInOut(i, images) {
$(images[i]).fadeIn("slow").delay(2000).fadeOut();
//alert(images[i]);
}
```

my problem is that only the first banner is displaying and in the alert only the first id is showing. Is there a better solution to this problem?

thanks....

Comment: first before made any changes in your code modified from `$(Document)` to `$(document)`, second could you show us the html associated and What's the error that appears in the console

Comment: Very true. Change to lowercase.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the delay. Different time zones. I will give them a try and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Overview

This answer comes in two parts: Help with the actual code you posted, and then a recommendation for another way to do it

### Help with the code you posted

This code:

```
for (var i in images) {
    setTimeout(fadeInOut(i, images), 5000);
    //alert(i);
}
```

...has one major and one minor issue:

1. The major issue: You're **calling** the `fadeInOut` function and passing its *return value* into `setTimeout`, just like any other time you do `function1(function2(arg, arg2));`. Instead, change the `setTimeout` line to:

   ```
   setTimeout(createFader(i, images), 5000);
   ```

   ...and add a `createFader` function that looks like this:

   ```
   function createFader(index, array) {
       return function() {
           fadeInOut(index, array);
       };
   }
   ```

   The `createFader` function creates a function that, when called, will call `fadeInOut` with the arguments you passed into it. You **cannot** just do this:

   ```
   setTimeout(function() {  // <== WRONG, WILL NOT WORK
       fadeInOut(i, images);
   }, 5000);
   ```

   ...because the anonymous function there (which is a *closure*) will get an *enduring reference* to `i` and `images`, and so when the timeout occurs, it'll use whatever their values are *then*, not what they were when you created the function. More: [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)

   (Don't use strings with `setTimeout` as another answer <s>suggests</s> suggested.)
2. `for..in` is for looping through the enumerable property names of an object, **not** for looping through array indexes. In trivial environments, it mostly works, but it's a bad habit that **will** bite you if you don't understand exactly what you're doing. More here: [*Myths and realities of `for..in`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/11/myths-and-realities-of-forin.html) If you're using jQuery, and if it's okay to have the overhead of a couple of function calls, [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) is great for looping through arrays (except it's not ideal for sparse arrays, but yours isn't sparse).

Separately, note that `new Array()` is better written `[]`, and in fact you can put the entries directly in the square brackets rather than doing assignment after-the-fact. And of course, it's `document` (in all lower case), not `Document` with a capital D.

So putting those all together:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var images = [
        "#bannerImageOne",
        "#bannerImageTwo"
    ];
    var i;

    $('#homeCarousel img').hide();

    for (i = 0; i < images.length; ++i) {
        setTimeout(createFader(i, images), 5000);
    }
});

function createFader(index, array) {
    return function() {
        fadeInOut(index, array);
    };
}

function fadeInOut(i, images) {
    $(images[i]).fadeIn("slow").delay(2000).fadeOut();
    //alert(images[i]);
}
```

Also note that I moved the declaration of `i` to the top of the function, because that's where the JavaScript engine sees it anyway (details: [*Poor, misunderstood `var`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/poor-misunderstood-var.html)).

Unless you have a really good reason why `fadeInOut` has to be a global function, I'd move it (and `createFader`) into the function you're passing to `ready` so we create no global symbols at all. That also lets them both use `images` directly, so we don't have to pass the array reference around (not that that's expensive, it's totally fine). That would look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var images = [
        "#bannerImageOne",
        "#bannerImageTwo"
    ];
    var i;

    $('#homeCarousel img').hide();

    for (i = 0; i < images.length; ++i) {
        setTimeout(createFader(i, images), 5000);
    }

    function createFader(index) {
        return function() {
            fadeInOut(index);
        };
    }

    function fadeInOut(i) {
        $(images[i]).fadeIn("slow").delay(2000).fadeOut();
        //alert(images[i]);
    }
});
```

It works because by putting the functions inside the anonymous function you're passing into `ready`, we make them *closures* over the context of the call to that anonymous function. (See the link above about closures.) Even after the function returns (which it does almost immediately), the context is kept in memory and provides a handy container for our private data.

### Recommendation for another way

Since all that the `setTimeout` call is doing is delaying the start of the `fadeIn` by 5 seconds, the code can be much simpler if you use `delay` (as you already have to put a pause between the `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var images = [
        "#bannerImageOne",
        "#bannerImageTwo"
    ];

    $('#homeCarousel img').hide();

    $.each(images, function(index, id) {
        $(id).delay(5000).fadeIn("slow").delay(2000).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Or keeping `fadeInOut` as a separate function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var images = [
        "#bannerImageOne",
        "#bannerImageTwo"
    ];

    $('#homeCarousel img').hide();

    $.each(images, function(index, id) {
        fadeInOut(id, 5000);
    });

    function fadeInOut(id, delay) {
        $(id).delay(delay).fadeIn("slow").delay(2000).fadeOut();
    }
});
```

The `delay` takes the place of the `setTimeout` and all the images start to fadein after 5 seconds. (I also threw in an example of using [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to lop through the array.) If you wanted them to fade in *sequentially*, you could multiple the delay by the `index`:

```
$.each(images, function(index, id) {
    $(id).delay(5000 * (index + 1)).fadeIn("slow").delay(2000).fadeOut();
});
```

or

```
$.each(images, function(index, id) {
    fadeInOut(id, 5000 * (index + 1));
});
```

...which would delay the first image by 5 seconds, the second by 10, etc.

Comment: +1 The anonymous function part was especially informative. Thanks.

Comment: @T.J. +100 you need a **hero's-hero** badge! Thanks for sharing so patiently your knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

I currently figure out how to make a fade in out slider/banner/album  with controller using javascript and css only:

This, I referenced other peoples' codes and make some changes... (thks those guy who give me the first idea) and hope this can help you.

**In HTML:**

```
    <div class="slideshow-container">
        <div class=" fade"> 
           <img src="xxx" style="width:100%;">
           <img src="yyy" style="width:100%;">
          </div>
    </div>
<div id="cf7_controls" class="center" > 
 <span id ="slideshow-ctr-1" class="">1</span>
 <span id ="slideshow-ctr-2" class="">2</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
<style>
  .slideshow-container {
    max-width: 1180px;
    max-height: 615px;
    margin: auto;
  }

  /* Fading animation */
  .fade {
    -webkit-animation-name: fade;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes fade {
    from {opacity: 0.4}
    to {opacity: 1}
  }

  @keyframes fade {
    from {opacity: 0.4}
    to {opacity: 1}
  }

  /* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
  @media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    .text {font-size: 11px}
  }
  
  img {
    margin-bottom:0px; 
  }
</style>
```

which I use from.....internet i forgot

**And then in JAVASCRIPT**

```
 var slideIndex2 = 0;
  var myfun;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slideshow-container");
  showSlides2();

  function showSlides2() {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    slideIndex2++;
    if (slideIndex2 > slides.length) {
      slideIndex2 = 1
    }
    slides[slideIndex2-1].style.display = "table";
    myfun = setTimeout(showSlides2, 5000); // Change image every 5 seconds
  }
  
  $("#cf7_controls").on('click', 'span', function() {
    clearTimeout(myfun);
    slideIndex2 = $(this).index();
    showSlides2();
  });
```